# How can I simulate the connection of multiple devices at once?

Tags: load-testing, mobile

I have a client that's developing a system that allows any user within range to connect and use the service. A router will be on-site and allow anybody within range to connect via WiFi. A virtual "line" will be in place to service users on a first-come-first-serve basis. When the user connects, they are placed at the end of the line and must wait for the users ahead of them. I need to simulate about 30 devices connected and in the queue. My first thought was to use JMeter, but the system will only see 1 device. Is there a way to simulate multiple devices being connected to a router without actually using the physical devices?

Comment: Why do you think using JMeter the system will see only 1 device?